# Different colours for R input and output using listings

Tags: listings, r

I need to quote some R commands and a few scripts, and sometimes to show the output. I would like that the output had a different colour than the input, but I have no idea how to. A minimal example could be this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{frame=none,
  language=R,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  numbers=none,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  keywordstyle=\color{Blue},
  stringstyle=\color{Red},
  commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
# First attempt
# to use R
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
> x
[1] 1 2 3 4
> sum(x)
[1] 10
> mean(x)
[1] 2.5 
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to achieve is to have `[1] 1 2 3 4`, `[1] 10` and `[1] 2.5` in another colour, for instance in `DarkBlue`. Is it possible with listings? I have only found a similar reference in the post ["Coloring R input and output differently using knitr"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030174/coloring-r-input-and-output-differently-using-knitr) which I don't understand because I don't know what `knitr` is!

Comment: "I don't know what knitr is!" Well, *you don't know  what you're missing ...*  it is a R package that allow compile LaTeX+R with RStudio or from the command line. See for instance [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132724/11604) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511354/11604). There are 336 more questions with the `knitr` tag, so you have  enough examples for a rough idea of  what you're missing.

Comment: It sounds really interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `moredelim=**[is][\color{blue}]{@}{@},` to `\lstset` and then bracket the R output like this: `@ code output @`. Now you have `keywords` and code output both in blue. You might choose a different colour for the output to make the distinction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\lstset{frame=none,
  language=R,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  numbers=none,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  keywordstyle=\color{Blue},
  stringstyle=\color{Red},
  commentstyle=\color{DarkGreen},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  moredelim=**[is][\color{blue}]{@}{@},
  tabsize=3}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
# First attempt
# to use R
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
> x
@[1] 1 2 3 4@
> sum(x)
@[1] 10@
> mean(x)
@[1] 2.5@
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you. I will probably choose different colours anyway, but it was highlighting the output that looked quite difficult.