# How to pass a variable to a command in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, pgfmath, variable

I am trying to make a tax calculator for an invoice template and the idea is to pass the variable `subcost` to the command `\taxcalc`.

```
\newcommand*{\taxcalc}[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/(1.0-#2)-#1}%
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\newcommand{\vatTotal}{
     & & & {\bf BTW 21\%} & {\bf {\bf \euro\taxcalc{subcost}{0.21}}}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
```

The problem is, no matter what I try to do to `subcost`, the compiler keeps complaining:

> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `subcost' (in 'subcost/(1.0-0.21)-subcost').'

It works perfectly for the following:

```
\newcommand*{\total}[1]{\FPdiv{\t}{\arabic{#1}}{1000}\formatNumber{\t}}

\newcommand{\subTotal}{
    & & & {\bf Subtotaal (excl. btw)} & {\bf \euro\total{subcost}}
    \\*[1.5ex]
}
```

Can anyone help me? I've been googling for hours now in order to find how to correctly pass variables to functions in this language but no matter what I try, it only works if I hardcode a number.

`subcost` is defined as follows:

```
\newcounter{hours} \newcounter{subhours}
\newcounter{cost} \newcounter{subcost}
\newcounter{vat}
```

Comment: Where and how have you declared `subcost`?

Comment: There are no such things as variables in TeX, only macros and maybe some packages that emulate something like variables by setting macros and retrieving the values from their definition. E.g. in `pgf` you can do `\pgfkeyssetvalue{my/variableA}{10}` and then do `\pgfkeysgetvalue{my/variableA}` to get back the `10`.

Comment: The `\arabic{#1}` looks like you're using a counter for `subcost`, you can get the value of a LaTeX counter by using `\value{<countername>}`, e.g., `\pgfmathparse{\value{#1}/(1.0-#2)-\value{#1}}` could work if the first argument to `\taxcalc` is always a LaTeX counter.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: It's worth taking a look at the `sagetex` [package](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) which gives you access to a computer algebra system, [SAGE](https://www.sagemath.org/) which can handle calculations on the fly (e.g. first page of documentation) or [calculate statistics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305764/calculating-descriptive-statistics/305776#305776) easily. SAGE lets you program with the easy to learn Python language, such as in my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33129/using-python-within-latex-and-accessing-its-variables/33135#33135).

Comment: Another package which might be worth a look is `xfp`, which gives you the macro `\fpeval` that can be used for calculations. To e.g., assign a result of some computation to a macro you could do `\usepackage{xfp}\newcommand*\MyVarA{10}\newcommand*\MyVarB{20}\newcommand*\MyVarC{}\edef\MyVarC{\fpeval{\MyVarA/\MyVarB}}`

Comment: @Skillmon Goot point!  Besides macros there are also registers. In any case, when using macros or registers as place-holders for some token-sequences denoting whatsoever values, you need to know about expansion and about the order in time in which things get carried out during expansion. On the other hand the terms "variable" and "function", as used in many high-level-programming-languages, suggest that you can take the placeholder/the function-call for the value without needing to care about rules for expansion and the order in time in which tokens get replaced by other tokens...

Comment: Calculating with LaTeX is more or less a pain in the ass. Why don't you use lua?

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the concept of a LaTeX-counter differs from the concept of a mathematical function in PGF-math.

Seems with your first snippet the problem is:

`\taxcalc`'s first and second argument must be numbers or calls to defined PGF-math-functions—i.e., things which can be used for calculations with PGF-math-things.

But by `\vatTotal` as first argument the sequence `subcost` is passed to `\taxcalc`. That sequence does neither denote such a number nor denote a call to such a defined PGF-math-function.

PGF-math-things cannot/do not "know" that the sequence `subcost` denotes the name of a LaTeX-counter whose value is to be obtained.

PGF-math-things "assume" that `subcost` denotes the name of a PGF-math-function implemented by means of PGF-math-things for doing PGF-math-things and therefore "complains" that the function "subcost" is undefined.

*Another question is:
Why `\bf` twice, opening up two nested local scopes?
Seems one local scope and one `\bf` is sufficient. :-)*

You can modify `\vatTotal` to make sure that the value of the `subcost`-LaTeX-counter gets expanded "into" `\taxcalc`'s first argument before `\taxcalc` gets carried out. This way at the time of carrying out `\taxcalc` the first argument of `\taxcalc` will not be a character-sequence denoting the name of a LaTeX-counter but will be a number and thus something that is "understood" by the PGF-math-things.

Does

```
\newcommand*{\taxcalc}[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/(1.0-#2)-#1}%
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\newcommand{\vatTotal}{%
    &&&{\bf BTW 21\%}%
    &{\bf\euro\expandafter\taxcalc\expandafter{\number\value{subcost}}{0.21}}%
    \\*[1.5ex]%
}
```

work?

Perhaps `\textbf{..}` instead of `{\bf...}`:

```
\newcommand*{\taxcalc}[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/(1.0-#2)-#1}%
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\newcommand{\vatTotal}{%
    &&&\textbf{BTW 21\%}%
    &\textbf{\euro\expandafter\taxcalc\expandafter{\number\value{subcost}}{0.21}}%
    \\*[1.5ex]%
}
```

---

Your second snippet works because here the sequence `subcost` is wrapped into `\arabic{...}` by the routine `\total` while the argument of `\arabic` **must** denote the name of a LaTeX-counter.
In other words: Here `\total` takes into account that `subcost` denotes the name of a LaTeX-counter by applying `\arabic` to that phrase  for obtaining a number which FP-math-stuff can calculate with.

---

Summa summarum:

The routine `\taxcalc` from your first snippet processes two arguments whereof each must denote a number or a call to a defined PGF-math-function which in turn delivers a number.

The *name* of a LaTeX-counter neither denotes such a number nor denotes the call to a defined PGF-math-function.
Therefore you need steps for obtaining the *value/number* from the name of the LaTeX-counter.

The routine `\total` processes one argument which must denote the name of a LaTeX-counter.

`\total` internally applies `\arabic` for obtaining a number from that which FP-math-thingies can use for calculating.

---

By the way:

If PGF-math is in use, then I prefer [Schrödinger's cat's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/516831/118714) of not using LaTeX-counters at all for holding values of "variables" but using PGF-math-functions that don't process arguments but always deliver the same number.
(Reason: Each LaTeX-counter internally requires allocation of a count-register while the amount of count-registers is limited in LaTeX. Afaik declaring a new PGF-math-function doesn't require allocating another count-register.)

In case a PGF-math-function does not process arguments and always delivers the same number, the name of that PGF-math-function within the context of PGF-math can be taken for a placeholder for that number/for a variable whose value is that number.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach works. You can declare a variable, or parameterless function, with `pgf` which you seem to be using. In order to be able to redefine the function, you need the starred version, `\pgfmathdeclarefunction*`. This allows you to define a variable and assign it a value which you can use in any expression that you parse with `pgf`. For your convenience, I packed the `\pgfmathdeclarefunction*` stuff in a macro `\SetPgfVariable`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\newcommand*{\taxcalc}[2]{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1/(1.0-#2)-#1}%
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\newcommand{\SetPgfVariable}[2]{%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{#1}{0}{\pgfmathparse{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\SetPgfVariable{subcost}{0.4}
\taxcalc{subcost}{0.21}

\SetPgfVariable{subcost}{0.5}
\taxcalc{subcost}{0.21}
\end{document}
```

[image]